# bad ssl certificate due to man in the middle, but I would like to inspect the certificate to see what the information is on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate

So I know in windows, when you have a bad certificate, you can just use the browser and click to check who the signer is.

However, I can't seem to do this in ubuntu cli?  How can I see which certificate is being offered to my ubuntu?  So I can see which certificate i may need to install?

```
stack@openstack:~/devstack$ curl -f --retry 6 --retry-delay 5 -z /opt/stack/devstack/files/get-pip.py -o /opt/stack/devstack/files/get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -verbose
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 151.101.0.175...
* Connected to bootstrap.pypa.io (151.101.0.175) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 594 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / 
ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OpenSSL` for that.

Install `OpenSSL`,

```
sudo apt install openssl
```

then use following command,

```
cat <path to certificate file> | openssl x509 -text
```

Comment: You forgot `cat`

Comment: I'm a little confused about the path to certificate pem file, did curl download the server certificate somewhere or do I have to download it manually somehow

Comment: how would I narrow it down which one it is?  They all have unique names and the date doesnt match what is today

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38 Mar 26 17:08 5c44d531.0 -> Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38 Mar 26 17:08 3d441de8.0 -> Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 26 17:08 6d41d539.0 -> Amazon_Root_CA_2.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Mar 26 17:08 fb5fa911.0 -> Amazon_Root_CA_2.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1005 Mar 26 18:28 ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 Mar 26 18:28 e6e41e31 -> ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
stack@openstack:/etc/ssl/certs$
stack@openstack:/etc/ssl/certs$ date
Mon Sep 24 18:18:58 PDT 2018

Comment: you can use `openssl` command again to check which certificate is used for certain request, for example, `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443`

Answer (score 0):

Use a program like `tshark` to capture the `ssl` and look for the ServerCertificates message... It has everything you need right there.